# Python auto importer for Sublime Text

Tags: python, autocomplete, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, auto-import

> I believe Sublime Text is by far the most optimized and powerful "text
> editor".

However, for writing any code you need some IDE-like features that help you write code faster and more efficiently and that's where `sublime plugins` come into the picture, there are a lot of plugins using which you can get `similar features like any IDE`.

But one thing I couldn't replicate which was `auto-generating python import statement`, I have tried many plugins `LSP`, `conda`, `Jedi` etc, but none of them worked or were **too hard to setup** and most of them are now **inactive** projects so if i had any issues it was harder to get resolution.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is only intended to promote OP's own code product.

Answer (score 1):

[image: cover image]

## Introducing `PyRock`

After desperate attempts i decided to build a plugin called `PyRock` whose "**First**" objective was to `generate Python import statements` for `libraries installed` in your `Python virtual` as well as `global environment` or from your `project codebase`, it does all very seamlessly.

Its very easy to use too, just the install the plugin using [sublime package control](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PyRock) and if you have python set globally it will `scan its package automatically`, and it also supports for `scanning your virtual environment` too, just follow the readme to update the setting and you are good to go.

So I do request anyone who works with `Python` and is in `love with Sublime Text` do try `PyRock`.

> There are lots of utility feature which i am planning to add which will
> help working with python more easily and efficiently. So please do try
> it, because it motivates me to work on it more often.

Its `open sourced` so if you want to contribute to it, you are more then welcome.
[Github repo](https://github.com/abhishek72850/pyrock)

[image: plugin usage demo]